# App currently on Android Market does not support tablets. Should be for phones only

Tags: android, tablet, screen-size

I finished my application and prepared it for distribution on Android Market. It is currently available. Before we begin to advertise the app, we are working to get the problems fixed. We only have it available so we can distribute to people who do not live nearby. My question, then, is that it works PERFECTLY on any smartphone we have thrown at it. A lady we know tried it on her Galaxy tab and it crashes out. I can replicate this error in the android emulator. All my code is correct, except for the fact that I have large and xlarge screens set to false in my support screens tag. My minSdkVersion is set for android 1.6

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supports-screens tag in the AndroidManifest.xml is used only by the Market for filtering apps. By setting large and xlarge to false, you should be excluding all tablets via the Market.  Tablet users will simply not see your app in searches or via browsing.  However, that will not stop a crafty user from side-loading your app on a tablet if they get hold of the APK file (perhaps by installing it to a smartphone and then extracting the APK from the phone).

If you posted the error message you are experiencing along with a stacktrace and/or some logcat info, we'd be able to help you out better.  My guess (based on prior experience) as to why you're crashing on the GX tab has to do with organization of layouts and resources.  The Galaxy Tab is a large-hdpi device, and you may have your layouts/resources organized such that when run on the GX tab, it cannot locate a needed resource and simply crashes.

Check out this doc at the Android developer's website for more info:
[How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Comment: Here is the error i am getting on the tablet screen. "The application MyApplication (process com.exampleapplication.myapplication) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." and the only button i get is "Force Close" (obviously I substituted MyApplication and com.exampleapplication.myapplication for the actual titles.

Comment: The Force Close dialog is pretty generic, and doesn't provide any useful developer info on screen.  What we'd like to see is a java stack trace, from the logcat output.  From a shell, run 'adb logcat', and copy/paste the section of the log that gets output at the time of the crash.  (Alternatively you can use the 'logcat' tab in the DDMS perspective, if you are using Eclipse).

Comment: Another possiblity as to what is causing your crash: check your layout files to make sure they are consistent.  If you define three versions of a layout file - say normal-hdpi/mylayout.xml, large-mdpi/mylayout.xml, and xlarge-mdpi/mylayout.xml, make sure they have the same UI widgets defined, with consistent IDs.  Quite often your activity code has calls like findViewById(R.id.some_widget).  If some_widget is in one of the layouts, but not the others, it will  return null on some devices and crash with a NullPointerException.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo        This is what is being called in logcat

Comment: Could you post the stack trace, and also the java code that's producing the exception?